# Arg parse: parse file name as string (python)

Tags: python, string, filenames, argparse

I would like to parse the name of a file into my script as a string, rather than directly converting the file into an object.

Here is a sample code, `test.py`:

```
import argparse
import os.path
def is_valid_file(parser, arg):
      if not os.path.exists(arg):
           parser.error("The file %s does not exist! Use the --help flag for input options." % arg)
      else:
           return open(arg, 'r')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='test') 
parser.add_argument("-test", dest="testfile", required=True,
                    help="test", type=lambda x: is_valid_file(parser, x))
args = parser.parse_args()    
print args.testfile
```

`testfile` is a `.txt` file containing: `1,2,3,4`

In principal would like `print args.testfile` to return the invoked name of `testfile` as a string:

```
$ python test.py -test test.txt
>> "test.txt"
```

To achieve this I need to prevent argparser from converting test.txt into an object. How can I do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: have you tried `parser.add_argument("-test", dest="testfile", required=True,
                    help="test")`

Comment: Thanks Jean-François, I had written a previous function to check the existence of the files, removing this from the code solves the problem.

Comment: The aforementioned function: 

#_____
def is_valid_file(parser, arg):
    if not os.path.exists(arg):
        parser.error("The file %s does not exist! Use the --help flag for input options." % arg)
    else:
        return open(arg, 'r')
#_______

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can modify your function as follows to return the string after having checked it exists:

```
def is_valid_file(parser, arg):
      if not os.path.exists(arg):
           parser.error("The file %s does not exist! Use the --help flag for input options." % arg)
      else:
           return arg
```

There's also a more direct method:

```
parser.add_argument("-test", dest="testfile", required=True,
                    help="test", type=file)  # file exists in python 2.x only

parser.add_argument("-test", dest="testfile", required=True,
                    help="test", type=lambda f: open(f))  # python 3.x

args = parser.parse_args()    
print(args.testfile.name)  # name of the file from the file handle
```

actually `args.testfile` is the file handle, opened by argparser (exception if not found). You can read from it directly.

Answer (score 1):

The `FileType` type factory does most of what your code does, with a slightly different message mechanism:

```
In [16]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [17]: parser.add_argument('-f',type=argparse.FileType('r'))

In [18]: args=parser.parse_args(['-f','test.txt'])
In [19]: args
Out[19]: Namespace(f=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='test.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>)
In [20]: args.f.read()
Out[20]: '  0.000000,  3.333333,  6.666667, 10.000000, 13.333333, 16.666667, 20.000000, 23.333333, 26.666667, 30.000000\n'
In [21]: args.f.close()
```

For a valid name it opens the file, which you can use and close.  But you can't use it in a `with` context.

If the file doesn't exist it exits with usage and a `cant open` message.

```
In [22]: args=parser.parse_args(['-f','test11.txt'])
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-f F]
ipython3: error: argument -f: can't open 'test11.txt': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test11.txt'
```

`FileType` `__call__` handles the error with an `argparse.ArgumentTypeError`

```
   except OSError as e:
        message = _("can't open '%s': %s")
        raise ArgumentTypeError(message % (string, e))
```

Using this error mechanism, and omitting your `open` I'd suggest:

```
def valid_file(astring):
    if not os.path.exists(astring):
        msg = "The file %s does not exist! Use the --help flag for input options." % astring
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(msg)
    else:
        return astring
```

Which could be used as:

```
In [32]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [33]: parser.add_argument('-f',type=valid_file)

In [34]: args=parser.parse_args(['-f','test11.txt'])
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-f F]
ipython3: error: argument -f: The file test11.txt does not exist! Use the --help flag for input options.
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2

In [35]: args=parser.parse_args(['-f','test.txt'])
In [36]: args
Out[36]: Namespace(f='test.txt')
In [37]: with open(args.f) as f:print(f.read())
  0.000000,  3.333333,  6.666667, 10.000000, 13.333333, 16.666667, 20.000000, 23.333333, 26.666667, 30.000000
```

http://bugs.python.org/issue13824 worries about `FileType` opening a file but not closing it.  I proposed a `FileContext`, modeled on `FileType`, but instead of opening the file, returns an object that can be use as:

```
with arg.file() as f:
    f.read()
```

It would do the file existence or creatablity testing, without actually opening or creating the file.  It's a more complicated solution.